# Calling action creator inside the function. Error:Actions may not have an undefined "type" property?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know action creator should have a type of property only then it would be able to dispatch. Since I am having a function call which ultimately leads to one action creator which have type property then Why it is showing me this problem.

When I tried to directly dispatch start game action creator it works but since I have to implement some more function inside them so I needed then inside the function. 
How to implement the same?

```
Menu.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {startGame} from '../actions';
import {loadMenu} from '../actions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
const page_Banner={
    marginTop:'35px',
    fontSize:'45px',
    textAlign:'center',
    letterSpacing:'20px',
    fontWeight:'bold'
};
const spacebar_screen={
    marginTop:'35px',
    color:'grey'
}

class Menu extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(loadMenu());
        console.log(this.props.dispatch);  
        console.log(this.props.isPlaying);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={page_Banner}>
                Redux    Tetris
                {!this.props.isPlaying?<h2 style={spacebar_screen}>Press spacebar to start the game</h2>:null}    
            </div>
        )   
    }
}
Menu.propTypes={
    isPlaying:PropTypes.bool,
}
// function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
//     return bindActionCreators({loading:loadMenu},dispatch);
// }
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isPlaying: state.gameStatus.currentState !== 'IDLE',
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu);




Action.js
import constants from "../gameConstants/constants";
export const startGame=()=>{
    const ShapeMapping=constants;
    const current_Shapeno=Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
    const next_Shapeno=Math.floor(Math.random()*7);
    const current_Shape=ShapeMapping[current_Shapeno];
    const next_Shape=ShapeMapping[next_Shapeno];
    return {
        type:"START_GAME",
        current_Shape,
        next_Shape
    };
}
export const pauseGame = () => ({
    type: "PAUSE_GAME",
});
export const unpauseGame = () => ({
    type: "UNPAUSE_GAME",
});
export const gameOver = () => ({
    type: "GAME_OVER",
});
export const loadMenu=()=>({
    function(dispatch,getState){
        function handleSpacebar(event){
            if(event.keyCode==32){
                dispatch(loadGame());
                window.removeEventListener('keyup',handleSpacebar);
                console.log('here')
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('keyup',handleSpacebar);
    }
})
export const loadGame=()=>({
    function (dispatch,getState){
        dispatch(startGame());
    }
})
```

Comment: Give keys to current and new shape and try it out. First look at your code that looks like an issue to me. return {
        type:"START_GAME",
        current: current_Shape,
        next: next_Shape
    };

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `loadMenu` and `loadGame` action creators. You're returning an object with an anonymous function which doesn't make any sense. An action creator is supposed to return an object with a `type` and the minimal data to define the action and return a function if you're using `redux-thunk`.

Keep the actions creators clean like you've done in `gameOver` and handle everything else in reducers or using the redux pub/sub pattern.

See this answer by Dan Abramov https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/787